What if the nth iterator is not within the range [first, last) when use std::nth_element
I cannot find any official definition related to handling of std::nth_element(first, nth, last) if nth is outside range [first, last).
As an attempt to figure it out, I did a toy test on my machine:
std::vector<int> arr{ 7, 3, 9, 6, 4 };
std::nth_element( arr.begin() + 1, arr.begin(), arr.end() );
for (int num : arr) {
    printf("%d", num);
}

MSVC gives me assertion fail in stl src code of vector, saying "vector iterator range transposed". Is it an undefined behavior?

Not official as the standard, but cppreference is good enough std::nth_element, and it covers your case.

Yes, it is undefined behaviour if

[first, nth) or [nth, last) is not a valid range.

Which says as much as that nth needs to lie between first and last.
